# Custom error headings for form validation doesn't display properly

Tags: ajax, forms, validation, form-submit

My contact form uses ajax, however, when you try to validate the form without filling in any of the fields, only three out of the four error messages display. The 'last name', 'email address' and 'message' error headings display, but the 'first name' error heading does not. 
When I take out the 'last name' error field and retest, the 'first name' field displays.

I have tried expanding the box to make it large, thinking there was simply no room for all four error headings to display, but I don't think that is the case. How can I correct this so that all four error messages (headings) display if a user does not fill out any of the fields?

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form #response').hide();


    $('.button').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var valid = '';
        var required = ' is required.';
        var first = $('form #first').val();
        var last = $('form #last').val();
        var email = $('form #email').val();
        var message = $('form #message').val();
        var tempt = $('form #tempt').val();
        var tempt2 = $('form #tempt2').val();

        if (first = '' || first.length <= 1) {
            valid = '<p>Your first name' + required + '</p>';
        }

        if (last = '' || last.length <= 1) {
            valid = '<p>Your last name' + required + '</p>';
        }

        if (!email.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
            valid += '<p>Your email address' + required + '</p>';
        }

        if (message = '' || message.length <= 4) {
            valid += '<p>A message' + required + '</p>';
        }

        if (tempt != 'http://') {
            valid += '<p>We can\'t allow spam bots.</p>';
        }

        if (tempt2 != '') {
            valid += '<p>A human user' + required + '</p>';
        }

        if (valid != '') {
            $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('error')
                .html('' +valid).fadeIn('fast');
        }

        else {
            $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('processing').html('Sending...').fadeIn('fast');

            var formData = $('form').serialize();
            submitForm(formData);
        }

    });

});

function submitForm(formData) {

    $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: 'mail/mailform.php',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            timeout: 4000,
            success: function(data) {

                            $('form #response').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
                                            .html(data.msg).fadeIn('fast');

                            if ($('form #response').hasClass('success')) {
                                setTimeout("$('form #response').fadeOut('fast')", 4000);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                        $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('error')
                                    .html('<p>There was an <strong>' + errorThrown +
                                        '</strong> error due to an <strong>' + textStatus +
                                        '</strong> condition.</p>').fadeIn('fast');
                    },
                    complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {

                        $('form')[0].reset();
                    }

          });


};
```

HTML ----------->>

```
<form class="contact-me" action="mail/mailform.php" method="post" name="contact-me">

<div id="response"><!-----------------CONTAINS FORM ERROR MESSAGE--------------></div>
<input name="First" class="required" title="Your First Name is Required" id="first" autofocus placeholder="First Name" type="text" maxlength="15"></input><br>
<input name="Last"  title="Your Last Name is Required" id="last" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" maxlength="15"></input><br>
<input name="E-Mail"  title="E-Mail Address is Required" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" type="email" maxlength="50"></input><br>
<textarea name="Message"  title="Comments are Required" placeholder="Comments" rows="1" cols="50" id="message" onKeyDown="textCounter(this.form.comments,this.form.countDisplay);"onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form.message,this.form.countDisplay);"></textarea><br>
<input type="hidden" name="tempt" id="tempt" value="http://" />
<input type="hidden" name="tempt2" id="tempt2" class="clear" value="" />
<input name="countDisplay" type="text" id="countdisplay" value="2000" size="4" maxlength="4" readonly></input><br>
<button class="button" ontouchstart="('touchstart');">SEND</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always type `valid += "validation message"` instead of `valid = "validation message"` for each validation. You forgot the `+=` for the first name and last name validations.

Comment: Thanks Romain it worked. How come the 'last name' field showed, but the 'first name' field did not, when the code was written the same way?

Comment: Because when the last name is invalid, `valid = '<p>Your last name' + required + '</p>';` overrides all previous values of `valid`, including the first name error message.